# Domain of Euler product

Tags: euler-product

I heard that Euler product is defined where s>1(real number).
$$\zeta(s) =\prod_{p=prime} (1 - p^{-s})^{-1}$$
but, Why? Why it  couldn't be defined where s is complex number?

Comment: Ir definitely is defined for some complex numbers $s$; more precisely, the product converges when the real part of $s$ is bigger than $1$.

Comment: It would not converge, like $\zeta(s)=\sum n^{-s}$, for all $s$ with $Re(s)\le 1$. Some people say that divergent products are "not defined".

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)